# WordPress Plugin Development - How to add a standard box to the options/settings page?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, settings

I want to add a few of the nice clean boxes used on most WordPress pages/posts in my Plugin Options/Settings page.

I was able to add a "meta box" to actual pages, but not to the Plugin Settings/Options page.
Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you, it's clear enough to indicate the methods of adding draggable meta-boxes to your plugin option page.

https://gist.github.com/bueltge/757903